# Blinking Text Block style throwing errors

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a style in XAML that can be applied to any TextBlock element to make the text blink.  Here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="BlinkingTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FlashMe" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlashMe" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I apply it to a text block

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Style="{StaticResource BlinkingTextBlock}" >
```

I get an error:

```
Must have a Storyboard object reference before this trigger action can execute.
```

Does anyone have an idea of where I need another storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all, you should bind to the "FlashMe" `StoryBoard`:

```
<BeginStoryboard  Storyboard= "{StaticResource FlashMe}" />
```

Comment: Bingo!  Knew it was something simple.